# how to get_class() with scope resolution operator in PHP?

Tags: php

Example:

```
<?php
class X {
    function foo() {

        echo "Class Name:".get_class($this)."<br>";
        echo get_class($this)::$private_var; //not working
        echo Y::$private_var; //works
        Y::y_method();  //works
        get_class($this)::y_method(); //not working
    }

    function bar() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

class Y extends X {

    public static $private_var = "Variable of Y Class";
    public function y_method()
    {
        echo "Y class method";
    }
}

$y = new Y();
$y->bar();

?>
```

Comment: some body please help, why i can't use get_class() with (::) operator.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the class name in a variable and then use that.

```
$class = get_class($this);
echo $class::$private_var;
```